# Command prompt says unable to find file when file is there

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, command-line, airsim

So I have a .py script that I am trying to run, and in either command prompt or anaconda prompt. If I run `python filename.py`, it gives me this error:
`python: can't open file 'C:\Users\tform\Documents\AirSim\CapstoneAPI.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

I am not sure how to solve this issue because the file is in that location. Do I need to mess around with some settings?

I am using Visual Studio 2019 as my IDE for python.

```
    import os
import os.path

import csv


import datetime
import airsim

client = airsim.MultirotorClient()
client.confirmConnection()
'''
First create a directory for all the csv files to store into.
''' 

dirmain = "C:\\AirSimData"
if not os.path.exists(dirmain):
    os.mkdir(dirmain)


'''
Create base format for file names that specify date and time of run
'''
run_date_and_time = datetime.datetime.now()
run_date_and_time_string = run_date_and_time_string = run_date_and_time.strftime('%y-%m-%d_%H%M%S')
extension = ".csv"
file_name_base = run_date_and_time_string + extension

'''
Create each sensor type file names and join then to savepath
'''
imu = "imu"
gps = "gps"
magnetometer = "magnetometer"
barometer = "barometer"

gps_file_name = gps + file_name_base
gps_output_file= os.path.join(dirmain,gps_file_name)

imu_file_name = imu + file_name_base
imu_ouput_file = os.path.join(dirmain,imu_file_name)

mag_file_name = magnetometer + file_name_base
mag_ouput_file = os.path.join(dirmain,mag_file_name)

bar_file_name = barometer + file_name_base 
bar_output_file = os.path.join(dirmain,bar_file_name)



gps_header = ['lat','lon','alt']
with open(gps_output_file,'w') as gpscsvfile:
    gpscsvwriter = csv.writer(gpscsvfile)
    gpscsvwriter = gpscsvwriter.writerow(gps_header)    





while True: 
  

    gps_data = client.getGpsData().gnss.geo_point
    alt = (gps_data.altitude)
    lat = (gps_data.latitude)
    lon = (gps_data.longitude)
    gps_data_struct = [lat,lon,alt]
    
    with open(output_file,'a') as gpscsvfile:
       gpscsvwriter = csv.writer(gpscsvfile)
       gpscsvwriter = gpscsvwriter.writerow(gps_data_struct)    

    imu_data = client.getImuData()
    s = pprint.pformat(imu_data)
    print("imu_data: %s" % s)

    #print("Altitude: %s\nLatitude %s\nLongitude %s" %(alt,lat,lon) )
    if False:
      break
```

Comment: could you include your code and also your directory?

Comment: When you don't provide a complete fill path, the file needs to be in the current directory. If you're using an IDE, it may not be what you think it is, You can see what the current working directory is with `print(os.getcwd())`.

Comment: @Shubham Nipanikar -How are things going? Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people said, when we use the command "`python name.py`" in the terminal to run a python script, we need to enter the parent folder of this python file so that it can be found.

[image]

Solution: We could use "cd" to go to the parent folder of the python file: (Please go to your folder "AirSim".)

[image]